# Centos 7 Extend partition with unallocated space

Tags: centos7, disk-space-utilization

I have centos 7 server `(CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core))` When I was updated my server I saw error you need extra space. But I had 20GB disk on server when I check disk spaces I saw only 4.5GB partition created and 16GB partition is free space no unallocated. 
How I can extend partition from 16GB free space?

**lsblk:**

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0               2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda               8:0    0   20G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0  4.5G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    4G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0  512M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

[image]

Comment: do `man lvm` or http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/

Comment: Anyone using an older Centos (like 6), this article worked for me https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1006371. Most important thing is to make sure you are using the correct Logical Volume name. Mine had been renamed to the hostname for some reason. `vgdisplay` will get you the name and the volume will be in `/dev/<vgdisplay name>/`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### There are three steps to make:

1. alter your partition table so `sda2` ends at end of disk
2. reread the partition table (will require a reboot)
3. resize your LVM pv using `pvresize`

### Step 1 - Partition table

Run `fdisk /dev/sda`.
Issue `p` to print your current partition table and copy that output to some safe place.
Now issue `d` followed by `2` to remove the second partition. Issue `n` to create a new second partition. Make sure the start equals the start of the partition table you printed earlier. Make sure the end is at the end of the disk (usually the default).

Issue `t` followed by `2` followed by `8e` to toggle the partition type of your new second partition to 8e (Linux LVM).

Issue `p` to review your new partition layout and make sure the start of the new second partition is exactly where the old second partition was.

If everything looks right, issue `w` to write the partition table to disk. You will get an error message from partprobe that the partition table couldn't be reread (because the disk is in use).

### Reboot your system

This step is neccessary so the partition table gets re-read.

### Resize the LVM PV

After your system rebooted invoke `pvresize /dev/sda2`. Your Physical LVM volume will now span the rest of the drive and you can create or extend logical volumes into that space.

Comment: a great solution, it works perfectly. still only the part how to extend logical volumes.

Comment: This excelent answer stopped just short of the finish line! I figured out how to finish it off. The example shared in the question showed two logical volumes underneith `sda2`: `centos-root` and `centos-swap`. In this case, the volume group is `centos` and the two logical volumes inside that group are `root` and `swap`. If we wanted to extend the `centos-root` volume in this example with 50% of the available space in our freshly-extended `sda2` partition, we would use `lvextend -r -l +50%FREE /dev/centos/root`. The `-r` resizes the underlying file system to match the extended logical volume.

Comment: @Shadoninja that's out of scope of the original question. So I didn't add it and will not add it to this question in the future.

Comment: @AndreasRogge I would argue that is entirely within the scope of this question as the terminology in this space can be confusing and easy to conflate. It is worth posting a complete summary of how to get unallocated disk space usable by the file system since that will be an extremely common reason for people to find this question.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me: ` pvresize /dev/sda2
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/sda2".
  0 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized`

Comment: I used this command on my centos box with 2 partitions: sudo lvextend -v -r -l +100%FREE /dev/centos/root. -v will give a great verbose output.

Comment: I agree with @Shadoninja, as extending a logical volume after extending the partition is what many intend to do as a use case. It's also what brought me here.

Comment: @TheKarateKid I'll happily answer another question concerning resizing the LV itself. However, it is usually not that simple and you need to resize the filesystem, too which is filesystem-specific again.
If someone finds a question that describes how to resize the LV itself, I will happily link it in my answer. Also, I would include the `partx` that @Aner suggested in his answer.

Comment: @AlexG I had the same problem. It seems (from `pvdisplay`, as well as `lvdisplay`) that I don't have any volumes. but that was not a problem, I've just ommited this step and the disk space is increased - I just had to increase the filesystem with `xfs_growfs`

Answer (score 44):

You can do this without rebooting in CentOS 7.  Assuming your disk is /dev/vda and standard RHEL/CentOS partitioning:

### Extend partition

```
# fdisk /dev/vda
```

Enter `p` to print your initial partition table.

Enter `d` (delete) followed by `2` to delete the existing partition definition (partition 1 is usually /boot and partition 2 is usually the root partition).

Enter `n` (new) followed by `p` (primary) followed by `2` to re-create partition number 2 and `enter` to accept the start block and `enter` again to accept the end block which is defaulted to the end of the disk.

Enter `t` (type) then `2` then `8e` to change the new partition type to "Linux LVM".

Enter `p` to print your new partition table and make sure the start block matches what was in the initial partition table printed above.

Enter `w` to write the partition table to disk.  You will see an error about `Device or resource busy` which you can ignore.

### Update kernel in-memory partition table

After changing your partition table, run the following command to update the kernel in-memory partition table:

```
# partx -u /dev/vda
```

### Resize physical volume

Resize the PV to recognize the extra space

```
# pvresize /dev/vda2
```

### Resize LV and filesystem

In this command `centos` is the PV, `root` is the LV and `/dev/vda2` is the partition that was extended.  Use `pvs` and `lvs` commands to see your physical and logical volume names if you don't know them.  The `-r` option in this command resizes the filesystem appropriately so you don't have to call `resize2fs` or `xfs_growfs` separately.

```
# lvextend -r centos/root /dev/vda2
```

Comment: More complicated answer then "selected answer" one !

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you! This should be the accepted answer. I was missing the last step to resize the lv and file system!

Comment: Also thank you, it worked.
For other readers, I got asked an extra question by fdisk while executing the above (centos 7.8), I answered with No, and it worked:
Partition #5 contains a LVM2_member signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: n

Answer (score 19):

Check this out — everything on a single line, no questions:

```
parted ---pretend-input-tty /dev/vda resizepart 2 100%;
partx -u /dev/vda; pvresize /dev/vda2;
lvextend -r centos/var /dev/vda2
```

Here:

- `parted` extends partition (`---pretend-input-tty` is a [hidden parted flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58840066/788700))
- `partx` updates kernel in-memory partition table
- `pvresize` resizes physical volume
- `lvextend` resizes logical volume and filesystem

This way reboot is not needed.

The above implies that you have vd* volumes, and under `vda2` there is an lvm volume group `centos` and lvm logical volume `var`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0               2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
vda               8:0    0   40G  0 disk 
├─vda1            8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─vda2            8:2    0   19G  0 part 
  ├─centos-var  253:0    0   17G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

If you have sd* volumes, like here:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0           2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda           8:0    0   40G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2        8:2    0   19G  0 part 
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0   17G  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

You can do it the same way:

```
parted ---pretend-input-tty /dev/sda resizepart 2 100%;
partx -u /dev/sda; pvresize /dev/sda2;
lvextend -r /dev/cl/root /dev/sda2
```

Comment: You should consider adding explanations and your environment. For instance, my partx doesn't have option `-u` (Centos6.7 util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.28.el6).

Comment: @Boop looks like it works on Centos 7.x + 8.x

Comment: this command worked perfect for me.  in my case I used ```centos/root``` instead of ```centos/var```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, with sda & sda3.  Other methods found on Google weren't working due to some weirdness in my disk configuration.

Answer (score 6):

For those who're having trouble extending logical volumes like me, reading [this post](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/) might be helping. In summary, 
you can use `lvextend` to extend your logical volume:

`lvextend -l +<PE> <LV_PATH>`

you can obtain the number of remaining PE(`<PE>`) by `vgdisplay` and obtain the path of your logical volume(`LV_PATH`) by `lvdisplay`.

Then depending on your distribution, you either want `xfs_growfs <LV_PATH>` (Centos 7) or `resize2fs <LV_PATH>` to finally resize.

Comment: +1 for including the `xfs_growfs` command. That's the part I was missing

Answer (score -1):

How can I do the same thing but with the example below.
https://prnt.sc/26s9s0w
https://prnt.sc/26s9uou

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/511864)