# Centos 7 Extend partition with unallocated space part 2

Tags: partition, lost, extend

If I delete a partition with step 1 from Andreas solution ([https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space)](https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space), and then I create new one, bigger partition, do I keep my data from this partition or they lost?

> Now issue d followed by 2 to remove the second partition. Issue n to create a new second partition.

Answer (score 4):

As the author of the earlier answer notes, the critical step to protecting your data is to

> Make sure the start equals the start of the partition table you printed earlier.

As long as you do that, the OS won't notice when you delete the partition, because it's using the memory-cached partition table that it set up at boot time (hence the error when writing the new partition table).  When you reboot, the OS will find the data where it left it, because the new partition begins in exactly the same place the old one did.  Sure, it ends a lot further on than it used to, but moving the *end* of a partition isn't a problem in the same way that moving the *beginning* is - which is to say, fatal for your data.

However, as with all such exercises, you should both take **and test** a full backup before doing any of this on live data.