# How to increase PV in Ubuntu after Virtualbox VDI resizing?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I did run out of disc space for the root partition in Ubunut 20.04. This is a guest system on Virtualbox.

Therefore I did:

1. Resized disk in virtualbox
2. Attached it to another linux box
3. Booted the other box
4. Resized pv

Now it looks like this:

```
sde                         8:64   0   25G  0 disk 
├─sde1                      8:65   0    1M  0 part 
├─sde2                      8:66   0    1G  0 part 
└─sde3                      8:67   0   14G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 252:2    0   14G  0 lvm  
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
user@rex:~$ sudo vgdisplay ubuntu-vg
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               14.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              3583
  Alloc PE / Size       3583 / 14.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               KVTTtl-f56L-SG26-iIVK-Wquq-5ZsL-LpDafi

sudo pvresize /dev/sde3
  Physical volume "/dev/sde3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

sudo pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sde3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  14.00g    0
```

The 25G apear to be there, but the PE still shows 14G. How can the volume be increased from here?

Comment: The PV is inside sde3, but is not really sde3. You didn't resize sde3, with a partition tool. See for example https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space/953625#953625 . Be careful, if using UEFI you should use an other tool like gdisk and must keep or put back the same uuid. Also don't accept the tool's offer to wipe PV signature.

Answer (score 1):

as A.B stated, you have to resize the partition first. Since this is the last partition on the disk, it can be done easily. I tend to prefer parted over fdisk in these situations.

```
parted /dev/sde resizepart 3 100%
```

And here is an actual dialog I had (just changed the diskname and partition number to match yours) while resizing from 44To to 50To. Note that parted asked all the questions again, strange but harmless.

```
root@server # parted /dev/sde resizepart 3 100%
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sde appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 20971520000 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
parted: invalid token: 3
Fix/Ignore? Fix
Partition number? 3
Warning: Partition /dev/sde3 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes
End?  [44.0TB]? 100%
```

The answers were **`Fix`**, **`3`**, **`Yes`** and **`100%`**.

Then, follow A.B's [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space/953625#953625) an continue with pvresize, lvresize etc...