# linux + how to extend sdd1 partition based on that sdd disk have enough space

Tags: centos, redhat, hard-drive, fdisk, parted

We have rhel server  7.2 version ( VM machine ) with sdd disk

sdd disk have parted partition `sdd1` , and our goal is to increase the sdd1 partition to 10g from current 1K size

From

```
lsblk

sdd                  8:48   0   20G  0 disk
└─sdd1               8:49   0    1K  0 part
```

so we expect to achieve sdd1 to became `10g`

We did the following examples but **without good results**

```
parted /dev/sdd
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sdd
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) resizepart
Partition number? 1
End?  [21.5GB]? 100%
(parted) q
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.


parted /dev/sdd
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sdd
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
 (parted) resizepart
Partition number? 1
End?  [21.5GB]?
```

we even installed the `growpart` command

```
growpart /dev/sdd 1
NOCHANGE: partition 1 could only be grown by -33 [fudge=2048]
```

Expected results ( from lsblk )

Any advice how to increase the sdd1 to 10g ?

s

```
dd                  8:48   0   20G  0 disk
└─sdd1               8:49   0    10G  0 part
```

Comment: I believe your `parted` method isn't working because you aren't modifying the partition table. Try the steps in Aner's answer on this post. https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centos 7 Extend partition with unallocated space](https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space)

Comment: no , I want the simple way ,

Comment: Show the actual partition table.