# CentOS LVM Extension Trouble

Tags: linux, lvm, partition, centos8, diskmanagement

We have a CentOS 8 server that has recently had a `lvm` fill up on available space. This was not our monitoring system since it watches the disk space and not the volume space. Regardless I am having trouble extending the space on the logical volume. Currently we have `sdb` which I have extended from 132 to 160. I think extended the `sdb3` partition to the max size putting it at 158.4. That then has two lvms under it, one at 128/128 and another at 2.4. The lvm I am trying to extend is called `cl_lifprodredo-root`, so I tried running the commands `lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/cl_lifprodredo/root` and then I tried the same command with `sudo` and adding the `-v` flag as well. Both commands failed to extend the lvm. I've attached the output of the command `sudo lvextend -v -r -l +100FREE /dev/cl_lifprodredo/root` as well.

[image]

If anyone has some additional advice on how to extend the lvm it would be greatly appreciated. It is a virtual machine so I am able to add additional space as needed, especially if the extra space needed to be allocated straight to the LVM and not the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added additional space to the disk and reran the commands from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space).

I had previously done so as well, and then ran `lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev...` with the correct file path. Previously when looking at the output of `pvs` it listed no free space, not sure if I just didn't run the `pvresize` or where my original attempt at extending the space went wrong but it has now been resolved with the process from the linked post and the `lvextend` command.